# What is the new feature introduced in the March 11th release for App ID?

Tags: ibm-appid

Would you let me know that what is the new feature introduced in the Mar. 11th release for App ID, such as new rest interface etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The new feature referred to is the IBM® Cloud App ID management API.

> The management API is secured with IBM Cloud Identity and Access
>   Management generated tokens. This means that account owners can
>   specify who on their team has which level of access for each service
>   instance. For more information about how IAM and App ID work together,
>   see [Service access management](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/appid/iam.html).
>
> With the API, you can:
>
> - automate the configuration of App ID in your app of your DevOps    process.
> - set and customize capabilities through your app back-end, such as    your login widget configuration, sign-up process, and user
>     management.

See more in this IBM Cloud [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/appid/api-reference.html#managing-app-id-with-the-api)